# MVC update model with Code-Migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, code-migration

I am making my project in MVC4, where i am using my Code first approach.  i need to update my model

i have a following property which needs to be update , how can i achieve this

```
public class ContactForm
    {
        public char Phone { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ContactForm> ContactForms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i want to update Phone propery to

```
public char Phone { get; set; }
```

thnx in advance, i have installed migrations to my projet already

My configuration.cs

```
namespace MyCRM.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyCRM.Models.ConContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(MyCRM.Models.ConContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part does not work? The update of the code, the migration on the console or the deployment to your database?

Comment: when i update this simply in the code , we have to drop my database always, which is not so gud @SamuelCaillerie

Comment: When you run `Add-Migration`, this generates a new c# file in your solution that you can update. What does it generates in your case : a drop of the old column and adds the new one? You can have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#customizing for customizing your migration.

Comment: Sure i am on this article

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie i update the question with configration.cs file, can you help me with the code to write to update, should i have to add code replace of commented out code

Comment: The file that I mentioned is in the directory "Migrations" and is called something like `20140923xxxxxx_yyyy.cs`. In this file, I have for example, some lines with `AddColumn("dbo.MyTable", "MyColumn", c => c.String())`, ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61775/discussion-between-user-died-and-samuel-caillerie).

Comment: are you around man @SamuelCaillerie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal flow with EF code-first is too first update the model (a C# file) :

```
public class ContactForm
{
    public string Phone { get; set; } //previously, this was let's say of type int
}
```

Then, you build your project and after that in the Package Manager Console, you have to call `Add-Migration` with some label (in order to rollback changes later if needed) :

```
Add-Migration Phone
```

This will add to your solution a file named like this `201409xxxxxxxx_Phone` under the directory `Migrations`.

Then you have to put the changes to your database which can be done with the command (always in the console) :

```
Update-Database
```

Then, you should be done : the property `Phone` is of type string everywhere.

Comment: absolutely great ! :)